# Ubuntu network problem in Hyper-V

Tags: 14.04, networking, hyper-v

I have problem with my Ubuntu server running in Hyper-V.

I received errors in `/var/log/syslog` and in virtual screen. When I see these errors my server can not response (network not working).

```
Nov 15 12:37:18 ser kernel: [595064.081322] hv_netvsc vmbus_0_13 eth0: unable to send receive completion pkt (tid 664)...retrying 1
Nov 15 12:37:18 ser kernel: [595064.081852] hv_netvsc vmbus_0_13 eth0: unable to send receive completion pkt (tid 664)...retrying 2
Nov 15 12:37:18 ser kernel: [595064.082237] hv_netvsc vmbus_0_13 eth0: unable to send receive completion pkt (tid 664)...retrying 3
Nov 15 12:37:18 ser kernel: [595064.082617] hv_netvsc vmbus_0_13 eth0: unable to send receive completion pkt (tid 664)...retrying 4
Nov 15 12:37:18 ser kernel: [595064.082889] hv_netvsc vmbus_0_13 eth0: unable to send receive completion pkt (tid 664)...give up retrying
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Kernel: Linux ser 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

it seems related to below bug which has been released

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1491957

Comment: So, for fix this problem I need wait new kernel or install old kernel - 3.16.0.46 ?

Comment: @PetroPikh I think you can help Joseph who fixing this bug. please refer last comment, and test his pkg. then you can comment the result. Thanks